# Added `startx` to autostart list, what to do now?

Tags: autostart

I made a stupid mistake and wrote command "startx" in autostart applications in Gnome. Therefore Gnome starts itself in cycle. How can I change autostart applications without logging into Gnome?

Comment: can you just add the ubuntu version you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Switch to the virtual console with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F1</kbd>  and type this command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after Login

```
rm ~/.config/autostart/startx.desktop
```

It should work.